# Use LAG Function on the latest row only

Tags: sql, sql-server, lag

I have a table that looks like this:

[image]

This table consists of many rows.  I want to use the LAG function to just calculate the date difference from between cyclestart and `getdate()` to get the cycleend time, on the latest record against the previous record, otherwise it calculates the LAG on all the records, and I cannot have that on such a large table.

```
select
    @AssetID,
    @ProductionDay AS 'Production Date',
    shift,
    SKU,
    CycleEnd AS 'Press Close Time',
    @shift12,
    cast( (CycleEnd - lag(CycleEnd) over (order by cycleend)) as datetime) as 'Cure Time'
from
    Cycle
where
    cycle.ID = @CycleID
```

If I use `TOP 1` or `TOP 2` then It gives me NULL in the cure time.

Comment: you can create a dummy record that has the `getdate()` , then Union your select last record with the dummy record which results in 2 records => use the lag function now

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.   I just don't understand this explanation:  "calculate the date difference from between cyclestart and getdate() to get the cycleend time, on the latest record against the previous record".

Comment: `lag(CycleEnd,1, GETDATE()) over (order by cycleend)` does that work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LAG()` accesses data from a previous row, and you are returning 1 row and there is no previous row, so it always return null.